# MYSQL GROUP BY pair of values with specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a period column in a table with values in the format `Year-SemiQuarter`. Example **2016-BQ1**, **2016-BQ2**, **2016-BQ3**.......**2016-BQ8**, where **BQ1** and **BQ2** would together make 1stQuarter for the respective year. SImilar for others

Now, I want to group the result by

**Quarter**

My table is something like this. Have splitted the period into two columns.

```
+====================+=============+================+==================================+=====+======================================+
| totalNumberOfUnits | productType | productSubType | SUBSTRING_INDEX(rsh.period, '-', 1  )  | SUBSTRING_INDEX(rsh.period, '-', -1) |
+====================+=============+================+==================================+=====+======================================+
|               1084 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ1                                  |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|               1284 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ2                                      |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|               1883 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ3                                       |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|                183 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ4                                      |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|                898 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ5                                       |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|               2377 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ7                                       |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
|               2953 | Apartment   | High Rise      |                             2018       | BQ8                                       |
+--------------------+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------+
```

The output should be :

```
+====================+==+
| totalNumberOfUnits |  |
+====================+==+
|               2368 |  |
+--------------------+--+
|               2066 |  |
+--------------------+--+
|                898 |  |
+--------------------+--+
|               5330 |  |
+--------------------+--+
```

So `totalNumberOfUnits` for 1st quarter for year 2018 is **2368** which is the sum of **BQ1 and BQ2**. Similar is for others. There is no data for BQ6, so the `totalNumberOfUnits` would be **898**, which the total number of units for `semi-quarter` *BQ5*

It could be very trivial but I am not sure how to do that. Couldn't find the same use case in Stack Overflow. Thanks for the help!!

The MySQL version I am using is **5.7.26**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string functions and aggregation:

```
select 
    left(period, 4) as yyyy, 
    floor((right(rsh.period, 1) + 1) / 2) as q,
    sum(totalNumberOfUnits) as totalNumberOfUnits
from mytable
group by yyyy, q
```

Comment: you could just use ceil instead of floor and +1 I think?

Comment: @ysth: yes indeed. I am just somehow more used to `floor()`.

Comment: Btw, ceil won't give the right value for BQ8. it would give 5, but expected is 4, so floor should be fine. Thanks!!

Comment: yes, when changing floor to ceil you also have to remove the `+ 1`

Comment: Right, sorry i missed the +1 in your previous comment. Thanks for clarifying!!

Answer (score 1):

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(rsh.period, '-', 1 ), (SUBSTRING_INDEX(rsh.period, 'Q', -1) + 1) DIV 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick:)